# How to add URL link in email body message in riemann

Tags: html, clojure, riemann

I am trying to add a html URL tag in my email body. I have used like below,

```
:body (fn [events] "Hello Team.\n Welcome \n  <a href=\"https://example.com/\">Link to my website</a>  \n * This is an automated e-mail and any responses to this e-mail will not be monitored \n Thank You!")
```

My html tag was not recognized . I am getting the output like below,

```
Hello Team, 
Welcome 
<a href="https://example.com/">Link to Kibana DashBoard</a>
 * This is an automated e-mail and any responses to this e-mail will not be monitored  Thank You!.
```

Do I need to use any filter to create a link in clojure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default you are sending a plain text email.

Riemann defers to Postal for sending emails, see [here](https://github.com/drewr/postal#attachments) for how to send HTML emails.